# Converting sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, sql-insert

How can I convert this subquery to join query or something more simple like with?

```
SELECT *
FROM ViewBuy99
WHERE Id NOT IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM Buy99
        )

INSERT INTO Buy99
SELECT *
FROM ViewBuy99
WHERE Id NOT IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM Buy99
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express this using `JOIN` as:

```
insert into Buy99
    select vb.*
    from ViewBuy99 vb left join
         Buy99 b
         on b.id = vb.id
    where b.id is null;
```

However, I would recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
insert into Buy99
    select vb.*
    from ViewBuy99 vb 
    where not exists (select 1 
                      from Buy99 b
                      where b.id = vb.id
                     );
```

Comment: Wouldn't we all love a real `ANTI-JOIN` syntax :-(